# how to write a trigger that checks if a value is already in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'd like to write trigger which checks if the product already exists in the given pallet and if it does, instead of adding a new row, just add the value to the old row

I have table:

| ID(pk) | product_ID(fk) | number of product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 14 |

And for exaple if i want add new row something like that (id: 2, product_id: 15, number of product: 13) I would like to get something like this:

| ID(pk) | product_ID(fk) | number of product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 27 |

Not like this:

| ID(pk) | product_ID(fk) | number of product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 14 |
| 2 | 15 | 13 |

I use orlace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I guess you could do this with a compound trigger. But why not just use a merge instead on an insert?

Answer (score 1):

Add row to table means insert. If you add unique index on both columns Id and product_id, after then while try to insert existing values the exception dup_val_on_index should happened. And if you insert and on insert gets dup_val_on_index exception you can overwrite it by update statement, no need to do trigger , all can be done on insert statement in exception statement

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it, I agree with what Alex commented - a `merge` instead of separate `insert` and/or `update`. I'd further suggest you to create a **procedure** which will be used to insert rows into the table. Why? It is simpler to call the procedure than to write the same (long?) `merge` all over again.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id          number constraint pk_test primary key,
  3     product_id  number,
  4     number_prod number
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_ins_test
  2    (par_id          in test.id%type,
  3     par_product_id  in test.product_id%type,
  4     par_number_prod in test.number_prod%type
  5    )
  6  is
  7  begin
  8    merge into test t
  9      using (select  par_id          as id,
 10                     par_product_id  as product_id,
 11                     par_number_prod as number_prod
 12           from dual
 13          ) x
 14    on (x.product_id = t.product_id)
 15    when matched then update set
 16      t.number_prod = t.number_prod + x.number_prod
 17    when not matched then insert (id, product_id, number_prod)
 18      values (x.id, x.product_id, x.number_prod);
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_ins_test(1, 15, 14);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID PRODUCT_ID NUMBER_PROD
---------- ---------- -----------
         1         15          14

SQL> exec p_ins_test(2, 15, 13);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID PRODUCT_ID NUMBER_PROD
---------- ---------- -----------
         1         15          27

SQL> exec p_ins_test(3, 99, 10);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID PRODUCT_ID NUMBER_PROD
---------- ---------- -----------
         1         15          27
         3         99          10

SQL>
```